com.distriqt.Core.ane - Unable to add to FflashBuilder 4.7
I'm trying to add "com.distriqt.Core.ane" to my FlashBuilder 4.7 project. The message below the ANE in the dialog box is "Extension XML is not present or is invalid".
I'm assuming this means the ANE is not listed in my application in the "extensions" section:
    <extensions>
        <extensionID>com.distriqt.CoreAAA</extensionID>
    <extensionID>com.distriqt.InAppBilling</extensionID>
        <extensionID>com.google.android.play</extensionID>
        <extensionID>com.distriqt.playservices.Base</extensionID>
    </extensions>

If I change each of the entries above by one character, go into the Native Extensions section of the dialog, then click okay, 3 out of four entries are simply updated - except the "com.distriqt.Core" is not updated, it is just ignored. This might sound a bit trivial but I'm just trying to look for something to latch onto in trying to get this ANE loaded and working.
This actually leads to the main problem in trying to get InAppBilling working on Android. I can log "InAppBilling.service.version" and it returns "15.4.0", so there is some functionality working with these ANEs. When I log "InAppBilling.isSupported" it always returns false.
Thanks!
Jason
Dialog of ANEs

com.distriqt.Core doesn't work. I used "AAA" to see it was updated correctly when I went in and out of the dialog box containing a list of ANEs. The other 3 updated correctly but this one is just ignore and cannot be loaded.
